# How to query places sorted by distance with lat, lng coordinates in MySQL with bookshelf.js or knex?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

Is it possible to search nearest places in mysql by using Bookshelf.js, or Knex? And, if yes, how to do it correct?

**UPD:**
I'm not strong with raw mysql queries, and can't find how to search with lat, lng in Bookshelf and knex.

For example, i have places table with:

- title
- address
- lat
- lng.

What query i should use to get all places in 10 miles radius from Point(lat, lng)?

thanks.

Comment: to be honest , YES !

Comment: Thanks, i think i was rush with question. And wrote nonsense

Answer (score 2):

After some research i found working solution:

```
const {lat, lng} = req.params;

const X1 = +lat - 10,
      Y1 = +lng - 10,
      X2 = +lat + 10,
      Y2 = +lng + 10;


const distanceInMilesSql = `( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(${+lat}) ) 
          * cos( radians( place.lat ) ) 
          * cos( radians( place.lng ) - radians(${+lng}) ) 
          + sin( radians(${+lat}) ) 
          * sin( radians( place.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        `;

const places = await new Place().query(qb => {
    qb.whereBetween('lat', [X1, X2]);
    qb.whereBetween('lng', [Y1, Y2]);
    qb.column(['*', Bookshelf.knex.raw(distanceInMilesSql)]);
    qb.having('distance', '<', 10);
}).fetchAll({withRelated: [
    'place_specific_fields',
    'state',
    'media'
]});
```

Comment: Are the qb.whereBetween lines necessary or are they redundant?

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**

http://rextester.com/NDOR4479

**SQL**

```
SELECT *,
       ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(:lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)) + COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lat))
       * COS(RADIANS(lng - :lng))) * 3959 AS distance
FROM places
WHERE  ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(:lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)) + COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lat))
       * COS(RADIANS(lng - :lng))) * 3959 <= 10
ORDER BY distance;
```

**Notes**

The above uses the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) where `:lat` and `:lng` are the latitude and longitude values from `Point` and `3959` is the Earth radius in miles.

Comment: Thank you, but the question was how to do it in knex / bookshelf.js.

Comment: Sure - posted this to get you going but wasn't sure exactly how to fetch the results as there seemed to be a few different ways of doing it in Bookshelf.js.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, here's some code I use (Strapi + MySQL):

1. Query for `events`
2. Join `locations` into `events`, where `id` matches
3. Gets anything within 5km (5000 meters) of the user

**On a side note:** As a Strapi user, a raw query like this negates the high-level functionality that Strapi auto-builds for the `events` model. ie Strapi url filtering like `&Cost_gte=20` won't work. I'm still working on how to get around this and avoid having to build an entire custom controller from scratch (all just to have distance filtering?).

**Code:**

```
const knex = strapi.connections.default
const result = await knex('events')
    .join('locations', 'events.Location', 'locations.id')
    .where(knex.raw(                
        `round(st_distance_sphere(
            st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(',locations.Longitude, ' ',locations.Latitude,')')),
            st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('POINT(` + ctx.query.Longitude + ` ` + ctx.query.Latitude + `)'))
        )) <= 5000`
    ))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't make it clear in your question, but I believe that the Bookshelf.js library works as a layer above PostgreSQL, which means that you have access to [geometric data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html). These can make use of [these special operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-geometry.html). The search could be entirely SQL based, so without further context I can simply offer the following:

Combine the latitude and longitude into a single data piece of type point (using the decimal form of the latitude and longitude). Here I will refer to that as `coord`.

With the proper data in order, you can do a query of:

```
SELECT p.*, (point'(@origin_long,$origin_lat)' <-> `coord`) distance
FROM `places` p
WHERE circle '((@origin_long, @origin_lat),@radius)' @> `coord`
ORDER BY distance;
```

If the data structures are set right, this should return a list, ordered by distance, of all pairs of coordinates within a given radius. You can set the coordinates at the top of this function, or maybe even wrap it in a stored procedure (if you don't mind the overhead).

For further reading, I know that PostgreSQL has an "[Earth Distance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/earthdistance.html)" function as well, so if you are looking to include the calculation of true distance traveled between points, it might be useful!

Comment: Bookshelf.js site says they work equally well with PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite. The OP tagged his question [tag:mysql], which *might* mean he uses MySQL (SO sometimes auto-tags questions incorrectly). Anyway, MySQL has its own geometric indexing syntax.

Comment: Yeah, i mentioned in title, thats i use mysql.